# Set html button active / deactive from flask context variables

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to change HTML button behavior from the Flask context.

```
<form method='post'>
   <button class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary" type="button" id='start' onclick="disableStartButton();">Start</button>
   <button class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary" type="button" id='stop' onclick="disableStopButton();">Stop</button>
</form>
```

Here how can I set Start button active and Stop enable from the flask app context?

Comment: Do you want to make the start button and stop button active/disabled onclick?

Comment: Can you explain how did you try (in Flask) to solve your problem?